# html code doesn't work properly in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function show_mcap()
{
    if(document.form1.marriage.checked)
    document.getElementById("m_cap1").innerHTML="Hall Capacity<br><input type=text      name=hall[]><br>Dining Hall capacity<br><input type=text name=d_hall[]><br>Rent<br><input      type=text name=rent[]>"
    else 
    document.getElementById("m_cap1").innerHTML=""
}

    function show_bcap()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("bday").checked)
         {
           document.getElementById("b_cap1").innerHTML="Hall Capacity<br><input  type=text name=hall[]><br>Dining Hall capacity<br><input type=text name=d_hall[]><br>Rent<br><input type=text name=rent[]>"
         }
          else 
          document.getElementById("b_cap1").innerHTML=""
      }
 </script>



 <form name="form1">
 <table>

 <tr>
 <td width="230"><label for="bday">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="marraige" id="marriage"     onClick="show_mcap()">Marriage/Reception
 </td>

 <td width="227">
 <input type="checkbox" name="bday" value="bday" id="bday" onClick="show_bcap()">Bday
 </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="m_cap1"></div></td>
      <td><div id="b_cap1"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code which i have written. This code works fine in chrome, internet explorer, opera. but doesn't work properly in mozilla! When i click on first check box, second check box is automatically selected! help me please

Comment: are you getting any error in your console ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe it has to do with your label. You specify the label around "marraige" to be 'bday'. Change this to be "marraige" and it should function as expected.

That is, change:

```
<td width="230"><label for="bday">
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="marraige" id="marriage"     onClick="show_mcap()">Marriage/Reception
</td>
```

To

```
<td width="230">
    <label for="marriage">
        <input type="checkbox" id="marriage" onClick="show_mcap()">Marriage/Reception
    </label>
</td>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JGMMj/ for a working example tested in Firefox. I'd like to note that there are other issues with the code, however this addresses the one you mentioned.